# conditional replacing with mode value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I've done already lot of searching but none of the tips I found was the expected answer.

Here is my df structure.

| year | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | Mick | a |
| 2001 | Mick | a |
| 2002 | Mick | ab |
| 2003 | Mick | b |
| 2000 | Jane | c |
| 2001 | Jane | c |
| 2002 | Jane | cd |
| 2003 | Jane | d |

And a list of values to replace:

```
values_i_do_not_want = ['ab', 'cd']
```

I'd like to replace a **value_i_do_not_want** with a mode for each name from **df['name']** column.

I like to receive a final df:

| year | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | Mick | a |
| 2001 | Mick | a |
| 2002 | Mick | a |
| 2003 | Mick | b |
| 2000 | Jane | c |
| 2001 | Jane | c |
| 2002 | Jane | c |
| 2003 | Jane | d |

[That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960264/how-to-replace-values-of-a-pandas-column-with-the-most-frequent-value) is what I found closest to my expectations. I couldn't implement condition to code presented there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby.transform` combined with `mode` to get the most frequent value, then use boolean indexing to replace the values:

```
df.loc[df['value'].isin(values_i_do_not_want),
       'value'] = (df.groupby('name')['value']
                     .transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
                   )
```

Output:

```
   year  name value
0  2000  Mick     a
1  2001  Mick     a
2  2002  Mick     a
3  2003  Mick     b
4  2000  Jane     c
5  2001  Jane     c
6  2002  Jane     c
7  2003  Jane     d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try groupby and transform

```py
df['value'] = (df.groupby('name')['value']
               .transform(lambda col: col.replace(values_i_do_not_want, [col.mode()]*len(values_i_do_not_want))))
```

```
print(df)

   year  name value
0  2000  Mick     a
1  2001  Mick     a
2  2002  Mick     a
3  2003  Mick     b
4  2000  Jane     c
5  2001  Jane     c
6  2002  Jane     c
7  2003  Jane     d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.apply` to check if the value of each row is in `values_i_do_not_want` and then find the mode of the values with the same name like this:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003],
    'name': ['Mick', 'Mick', 'Mick', 'Mick', 'Jane', 'Jane', 'Jane', 'Jane'],
    'value': ['a', 'a', 'ab', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'cd', 'd'],
})

values_i_do_not_want = ['ab', 'cd']

df = df.assign(
    value=df.apply(
        lambda x: (
            x.value 
            if x.value not in values_i_do_not_want 
            else df.loc[df['name'] == x['name'], 'value'].mode().iloc[0]
        ),
        axis=1
    )
)
```

output:

```
>>> df
   year  name value
0  2000  Mick     a
1  2001  Mick     a
2  2002  Mick     a
3  2003  Mick     b
4  2000  Jane     c
5  2001  Jane     c
6  2002  Jane     c
7  2003  Jane     d
```