# Aggregation function for groupby: Take the most frequent value but if its a blank, take the second most frequent value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate, pandas-groupby

**Edit:** clearified the question

I want to aggregate a pd.DataFrame called **df** by "Identifier" and sum the "Costs" columns. For the category columns I want to apply an aggregation function that can be spoken out loud like "aggregate and take the most frequent value (the mode) of the column, but if the mode is a blank than take the second most frequent column". In other words, I want to have the mode of the category (after aggregation) but the mode must not be a blank.

Result should be the pd.DataFrame **new_df**.

```
df
  Identifier  Cost  Cost2 Category1 Category2 Category3
0          A    10     10       one                 aaa
1          A    20     10                blue       aaa
2          B    10     20       two                 bbb
3          B    10     30               green       bbb
4          B    30     40                           bbb
5          C    20     50     three       red       ccc
```

--- aggregation process --->

```
new_df
  Identifier  Cost  Cost2 Category1 Category2 Category3
0          A    30     20       one      blue       aaa
1          B    50     90       two     green       bbb
2          C    20     50     three       red       ccc
```

Code to reproduce the example:

```
import pandas as pd

data_df = {       
           'Identifier': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
           'Cost': [10, 20, 10, 10, 30, 20],
           'Cost2':[10,10,20,30,40,50],
           'Category1' : ['one', '', 'two', '', '', 'three'],
           'Category2' : ['', 'blue', '', 'green', '', 'red'],
           'Category3' : ['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'ccc']
          }

df = pd.DataFrame(data_df)


data_new_df = {       
           'Identifier': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
           'Cost': [30, 50, 20],
           'Cost2' : [20,90,50],
           'Category1' : ['one', 'two', 'three'],
           'Category2' : ['blue', 'green', 'red'],
           'Category3' : ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
          }

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data_new_df)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GroupBy pandas DataFrame and select most common value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222754/groupby-pandas-dataframe-and-select-most-common-value)

Comment: filter out the blank values and follow the answer given in the linked question above?

Comment: Is cost column of B going to 50 instead?

Comment: As far as I understand, it is no duplicate. I want to take the most frequent value of the column, but in case the most frequent value of the column is a blank, I want to have the second most frequent (non-blank) value.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try `groupby` with `sum` following:

```
new_df = df.groupby('Identifier').apply(sum).drop('Identifier', axis=1).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
  Identifier  Cost Category1 Category2
0          A    30       one      blue
1          B    50       two     green
2          C    20     three       red
```

Comment: How would this answer work with multiple Cost columns?

Comment: Did you try the same code? I am little confused with your sum results, you have different values on result and scripts for values.

Comment: Sorry my fault, there was two little mistakes in the code. How can I use your code with two sum operations (on "Cost" and "Cost2")? Thanks in advance!

Comment: np, you can try same code, it should sum all the columns values.

Comment: works for the code I provides as an example, so answer accepted :) However if you dont mind, I got an error with my actual dataset: "ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>"  Do you have an idea?

Comment: I identified the problem: For some category columns I dont have blanks and in this case I want to have the most frequent value (mode) - again the aggregation function a la "aggregate and take the most frequent value other than blank" should be applied. For this purpose your one-liner does unfortunately not work - I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
new_df = df.groupby('Identifier').sum().reset_index()
new_df['Category1'] = df.loc[df.Category1 != '', 'Category1'].reset_index(drop=True)
new_df['Category2'] = df.loc[df.Category2 != '', 'Category2'].reset_index(drop=True)
new_df
```

Result:

```
  Identifier  Cost Category1 Category2
0          A    30       one      blue
1          B    50       two     green
2          C    20     three       red
```