# Finding the most common pair from two dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of people that, among many others, has columns for the city and type of pet each person prefers. I would like to find the city where a certain pet is most prevalent.

```
City             Pet
New York         Cat
Washington       Dog
Boston           Dog
New York         Cat
Atlanta          Cat
New York         Dog
Atlanta          Dog
Boston           Dog
```

So in this case, New York would have the most cats and Boston would have the most dogs.

How do I determine which city has e.g., the most cats for my larger dataframe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GroupBy pandas DataFrame and select most common value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222754/groupby-pandas-dataframe-and-select-most-common-value)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the full list sorted by the number of cats, you could do the following:

```
In [38]: df.groupby('City').Pet.value_counts().unstack().sort_values(by='Cat', ascending=False)
Out[38]:
Pet         Cat  Dog
City
New York    2.0  1.0
Atlanta     1.0  1.0
Boston      NaN  2.0
Washington  NaN  1.0
```

If you only want the largest one, you can use `nlargest`:

```
In [45]: df.groupby('City').Pet.value_counts().unstack().nlargest(1, 'Cat')
Out[45]:
Pet      Cat  Dog
City
New York 2.0  1.0
```

Or you could do the same but focus on cats from the beginning:

```
In [62]: df[df.Pet == 'Cat'].groupby('City').count().nlargest(1, 'Pet')
Out[62]:
         Pet
City
NewYork    2
```

If you don't care about the actual numbers and just want the cities, you can use `idxmax`:

```
In [51]: df.groupby('City').Pet.value_counts().unstack().idxmax()
Out[51]:
Pet
Cat   New York
Dog     Boston
```

If you want to do what the last example does, but only focus on cats, you can do that as well:

```
In [60]: df[df.Pet == 'Cat'].groupby('City').count().idxmax()
Out[60]:
Pet    New York
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try this: nlargest will return the top 'n' results, in this case I set
>   nlargest =1 so it returns the top result. I set animal = "cat", so you
>   can change to "Dog" and see the results for dogs..

```
df2  = df[df["Pet"] ==animal].groupby('City').count().rename(columns={"Pet":animal}).nlargest(1, animal)
```

[image]

Here is an alternative if you want the search to case insensitive (would count "Cat, CAT or cat" )

```
df2  = df[df["Pet"].str.lower() ==animal.lower()].groupby('City').count().rename(columns={"Pet":animal}).nlargest(3, animal)
```

Answer (score 1):

We using `mode`

```
df.groupby('City').Pet.apply(lambda x : pd.Series.mode(x)[0])
City
Atlanta       Cat
Boston        Dog
NewYork       Cat
Washington    Dog
Name: Pet, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a more pythonic way. But this should do what you need.

```
data = df.groupby(['pet','city']).city.count().to_frame() # getting the count of each pet at each city
data.columns = ['cnt']  # changing the name of the column
def set_max(series): # this is used to develop a new column that carries the maximum of that column
    return [max(series) for s in series]
data['maximum'] = data.transform(set_max) # add a column that carries maximum value
bm = data.apply(lambda x : x.maximum == x.cnt,axis=1)  # boolean mask that is true when the count=max
data.loc[bm].reset_index()[['pet','city']] # giving the results
```