# pandas groudby dataframe and get mean and most common value per group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'values':arrays,'ii':lin_index})
```

I want to group the values by the lin_index and get the mean per group and the most common value per group
I try this

```
bii=df.groupby('ii').median()
bii2=df.groupby('ii').agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0])
bii3=df.groupby('ii')['values'].agg(pd.Series.mode)
```

I wonder if bii2 and bii3 return the same values
Then I want to return the mean and most common value to the original array

```
bs=np.zeros((np.unique(array).shape[0],1))
bs[bii.index.values]=bii.values
```

Does this look good?

df looks like

```
          values        ii
0            1.0  10446786
1            1.0  11316289
2            1.0  16416704
3            1.0  12151686
4            1.0  30312736
     ...       ...
93071038     3.0  28539525
93071039     3.0  19667948
93071040     3.0  22240849
93071041     3.0  22212513
93071042     3.0  41641943

[93071043 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Add an example dataframe so we can your code is reproducable.

Comment: They return the same

Comment: One small change. Since I need only ONE value (in case 2 or more are the most common), i changed it like this  #bii3=df.groupby('ii').agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0])

Comment: Thing is that bii2 now is a Series and not a dataframe. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe:

```
# get the mean
df.groupby(['ii']).mean()
# get the most frequent
df.groupby(['ii']).agg(pd.Series.mode)
```

your question seems similar to
[GroupBy pandas DataFrame and select most common value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222754/groupby-pandas-dataframe-and-select-most-common-value)

this link might also be useful https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html#computations-descriptive-stats