# Extracting rows with most frequent value

Tags: python, pandas, filter, pandas-groupby

Have a dataframe with several columns from which I want to extract one row for each "family" of individuals that has  the most frequent number ("No"). I have tested this with a for -loop that seems to work, but being a newbe I wanted to know if there is a shorter/smarter way of doing it.

Here is a short example code:

```
import pandas as pd


ind = [ ('A', 'a', 0.1 , 9) ,
             ('B', 'b', 0.6  , 10) ,
             ('C', 'b', 0.4 , 10) ,
             ('D', 'b', 0.2, 7) ,
             ('E', 'a', 0.9  , 6) ,
             ('F', 'b', 0.7 , 11)
              ]


df = pd.DataFrame(ind, columns = ['Name' , 'Family', 'Prob', 'No'])

res = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)

for name,g in df.groupby('Family'):
    v = g['No'].value_counts().idxmax()
    idx = g['No'] == v
    si = g[idx].iloc[0]
    res = res.append(si)
print(res)
```

I have looked at several exampels that do some of it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222754/groupby-pandas-dataframe-and-select-most-common-value) but with that I can only get the "Family" and "No" and not the whole row...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative using [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and `mode+groupby` with mode:

```
c = df['No'].eq(df.groupby('Family')['No'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]))
c1 = df[['Family','No']].duplicated()
output = df[c & ~c1]
```

---

```
  Name Family  Prob  No
1    B      b   0.6  10
4    E      a   0.9   6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot #anky_91

Comment: @ErikThysell Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with first mode, then filter and last remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = (df[df.groupby('Family')['No'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]).eq(df['No'])]
         .drop_duplicates(['Family','No']))
print (df1)
  Name Family  Prob  No
1    B      b   0.6  10
4    E      a   0.9   6
```