# pandas.Series.mode returns ndarray instead of single value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, mode

I need to get pd.Series of single values from Series.mode function.
Example code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'],
                   'key': [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]})

modes = df.groupby('key')['A'].agg(pd.Series.mode)
```

```
key A
0   A0
1   A1
2   A2
3   ['A3' 'A4' 'A5']
```

The problem is row '3'. It returns numpy.ndarray.
How should I modify my script to get single values in all rows.
It is convenient for me to get any of mode values A3, A4, A5.

Comment: If you don't really care about which value in the case of ties, `mode` is essentially a groupby + size + sort + drop_duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68533960/multiple-modes-for-multiple-accounts-in-python/68534232#68534232

Comment: Yes, this code helps me absolutely! 



test.groupby('account')['category'].agg(
    lambda x: np.random.choice(x.mode(dropna=False)))

Answer (score 1):

You could [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) the output to get duplicated indices:

```
modes = df.groupby('key')['A'].agg(pd.Series.mode).explode()
```

output:

```
key
0    A0
1    A1
2    A2
3    A3
3    A4
3    A5
Name: A, dtype: object
```