# How to fill missing values in a DataFrame with the most frequent value of each group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a pandas DataFrame with two columns: `toy` and `color`. The `color` column includes missing values.

How do I fill the missing `color` values with the most frequent `color` for that particular `toy`?

Here's the code to create a sample dataset:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'toy':['car'] * 4 + ['train'] * 5 + ['ball'] * 3 + ['truck'],
    'color':['red', 'blue', 'blue', np.nan, 'green', np.nan,
             'red', 'red', np.nan, 'blue', 'red', np.nan, 'green']
    })
```

Here's the sample dataset:

```py
      toy  color
0     car    red
1     car   blue
2     car   blue
3     car    NaN
4   train  green
5   train    NaN
6   train    red
7   train    red
8   train    NaN
9    ball   blue
10   ball    red
11   ball    NaN
12  truck  green
```

Here's the desired result:

- Replace the **first NaN** with **blue**, since that is the most frequent `color` for a car.
- Replace the **second and third NaNs** with **red**, since that is the most frequent `color` for a train.
- Replace the **fourth NaN** with either **blue or red**, since they are tied for the most frequent `color` for a ball.

Notes about the real dataset:

- There are many different `toy` types (not just four).
- There are no `toy` types that only have missing values for `color`, so the answer does not need to handle that case.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222754/groupby-pandas-dataframe-and-select-most-common-value) is related, but it doesn't answer my question of how to use the most frequent value to fill in missing values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby()`+`transform()`+`fillna()`:

```
df['color']=df['color'].fillna(df.groupby('toy')['color'].transform(lambda x:x.mode().iat[0]))
```

OR

If want to select random values when there are 2 or more frequent values:

```
from random import choice

df['color']=df['color'].fillna(df.groupby('toy')['color'].transform(lambda x:choice(x.mode())))
```

Comment: beat me to it, +1 ;)

Comment: Doesn't that replace all the colors with the most frequent color for each toy? i.e. the color for each car is replaced with blue.

Comment: @norie ohh..yes corrected...thanks for noticing **:)**

Answer (score 2):

You want to `fillna` with the `mode`:

```
df["color"] = df.groupby("toy")["color"].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().iat[0]))
```