# GroupBy pandas DataFrame and select most common value which is alphabetically first

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with multiple columns but currently, I am focusing on **province** and **city** columns. The problem is I want to fill NaN values in the **city** column by the most frequent city value in the same province, but if the value count of any city is the same then it should fill with the one which is alphabetically first.
I followed an answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222754/groupby-pandas-dataframe-and-select-most-common-value) link and modified it, but values are not being sorted alphabetically for some reason.

Here's my code:

```
df.groupby(['province'])['city'].agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False).index[0])
```

what do I need to change?

Sample DataFrame:

```
{'province': {0: 'A',
  1: 'A',
  2: 'A',
  3: 'A',
  4: 'A',
  5: 'A',
  6: 'A',
  7: 'B',
  8: 'B',
  9: 'B',
  10: 'B',
  11: 'B',
  12: 'B',
  13: 'B'},
 'city': {0: 'newyork',
  1: nan,
  2: 'newyork',
  3: 'london',
  4: 'london',
  5: nan,
  6: 'houston',
  7: 'hyderabad',
  8: 'karachi',
  9: nan,
  10: 'hyderabad',
  11: nan,
  12: 'beijing',
  13: 'karachi'}}
```

Required Output:

```
{'province': {0: 'A',
  1: 'A',
  2: 'A',
  3: 'A',
  4: 'A',
  5: 'A',
  6: 'A',
  7: 'B',
  8: 'B',
  9: 'B',
  10: 'B',
  11: 'B',
  12: 'B',
  13: 'B'},
 'city': {0: 'newyork',
  1: 'london',
  2: 'newyork',
  3: 'london',
  4: 'london',
  5: 'london',
  6: 'houston',
  7: 'hyderabad',
  8: 'karachi',
  9: 'hyderabad',
  10: 'hyderabad',
  11: 'hyderabad',
  12: 'beijing',
  13: 'karachi'}}
```

Comment: Please include a sample of your DataFrame and your expected output.

Comment: @Rafaó it must be grouped because I have to check occurrence in each province, not in the whole data frame.

Comment: Avoid posting screenshots of data. You could include the constructor for your DataFrame with `df.to_dict()` so we can copy-paste to recreate your structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `groupby` and `mode`:

```
mapper = df.groupby("province")["city"].agg(lambda x: x.mode().sort_values()[0]).to_dict()
df["city"] = df["city"].where(df["city"].notnull(),
                              df["province"].map(mapper))

>>> df
   province       city
0         A    newyork
1         A     london
2         A    newyork
3         A     london
4         A     london
5         A     london
6         A    houston
7         B  hyderabad
8         B    karachi
9         B  hyderabad
10        B  hyderabad
11        B  hyderabad
12        B    beijing
13        B    karachi
```

Comment: It didn't help, the data doesn't have only equal city value counts, your code is replacing NaN values with the city which is alphabetically first in the same province. I have edited the question and added data frame as well. Maybe it will make sense now.

Comment: It worked but, can you explain why are we using `notnull()` when we are actually filling null values?

Comment: Where the values are not null, keep the original value, for the rest, map with the dictionary.