# How to get most frequent occurrences per unique id of multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with a unique customer_id and several order_id of each time a unique customer made a purchase. It's about the reading glasses, so I removed the product information and now I have just the strongness of the reading glasses (+1, +4, +2.5 etc).

My dataframe for this feature looks like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YnTw.png)

I've tried multiple things, such as:

```py
testdf = testdf.groupby(['customer_id', 'order_id'])['order_item1', 'order_item2', 'order_item3', 'order_item4', 'order_item5']\
    .agg(list)\
    .apply(lambda x:list(combinations(set(x),2)))\
    .explode()
```

and:

```py
def top_product(g):

    product_cols = [col for col in g.columns if col.startswith('order_item')]
    try:
        out = (g[product_cols].stack().value_counts(normalize=True)
                             .reset_index().iloc[0])
        out.index = ['most_product']
        return out
    except IndexError:
        return pd.Series({'order_item': 'None', 'most_product' : 0})

output = testdf.groupby('order_id').apply(top_product)
```

Both don't work. I would like to know of each customer which product they bought most. So for customer_id 11795 it would be 2.5. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Please provide the DataFrame in the question so we can copy it (we can't copy from image)

Comment: You're probably looking for the `mode` - see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222754/groupby-pandas-dataframe-and-select-most-common-value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GroupBy pandas DataFrame and select most common value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222754/groupby-pandas-dataframe-and-select-most-common-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first use `.melt()` to reshape the dataframe. Then you could do a `.value_counts()` on that column. Lastely, sort the dataframe by the count and drop duplicate customer_ids, keeping the first, which will leave you with the highest count for each customer.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {
        'order_id':[33163,38596,35326,46139,57446,65838,71228],
        'customer_id':[11795,11795,10613,10613,5729,5729,5729],
        'order_item1':[2.5,2.5,2,-2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5],
        'order_item2':[np.nan,2,2.5,np.nan,2.5,2.5,np.nan],
        'order_item3':[np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
        'order_item4':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
        'order_item5':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Data**

```
print(df)
   order_id  customer_id  order_item1  ...  order_item3  order_item4  order_item5
0     33163        11795          2.5  ...          NaN          NaN          NaN
1     38596        11795          2.5  ...          NaN          NaN          NaN
2     35326        10613          2.0  ...          2.0          NaN          NaN
3     46139        10613         -2.5  ...          NaN          NaN          NaN
4     57446         5729          2.5  ...          NaN          NaN          NaN
5     65838         5729          2.5  ...          NaN          NaN          NaN
6     71228         5729          2.5  ...          NaN          NaN          NaN

[7 rows x 7 columns]
```

**Melt: Use the `'order_item'` columns to melt as the values:**

```
itemCols = [x for x in df.columns if 'order_item' in x]
df_melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars='customer_id', value_vars=itemCols).dropna(subset='value')
```

**Melted output:**

```
print(df_melt)
    customer_id     variable  value
0         11795  order_item1    2.5
1         11795  order_item1    2.5
2         10613  order_item1    2.0
3         10613  order_item1   -2.5
4          5729  order_item1    2.5
5          5729  order_item1    2.5
6          5729  order_item1    2.5
8         11795  order_item2    2.0
9         10613  order_item2    2.5
11         5729  order_item2    2.5
12         5729  order_item2    2.5
16        10613  order_item3    2.0
```

**Value counts on the `'value'` column:**

```
value_counts = df_melt.groupby('customer_id')['value'].value_counts().rename('count').reset_index()
value_counts = value_counts.sort_values(['customer_id', 'count'], ascending=[True, False])
```

**Value Counts Output:**

```
print(value_counts)
   customer_id  value  count
0         5729    2.5      5
1        10613    2.0      2
2        10613   -2.5      1
3        10613    2.5      1
4        11795    2.5      2
5        11795    2.0      1
```

**Drop duplicate customer ids, keep the first:**

```
top_sales = value_counts.drop_duplicates(subset='customer_id', keep='first')
```

**Output:**

```
print(top_sales)
   customer_id  value  count
0         5729    2.5      5
1        10613    2.0      2
4        11795    2.5      2
```

**Full code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {
        'order_id':[33163,38596,35326,46139,57446,65838,71228],
        'customer_id':[11795,11795,10613,10613,5729,5729,5729],
        'order_item1':[2.5,2.5,2,-2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5],
        'order_item2':[np.nan,2,2.5,np.nan,2.5,2.5,np.nan],
        'order_item3':[np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
        'order_item4':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
        'order_item5':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

itemCols = [x for x in df.columns if 'order_item' in x]
df_melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars='customer_id', value_vars=itemCols).dropna(subset='value')

value_counts = df_melt.groupby('customer_id')['value'].value_counts().rename('count').reset_index()
value_counts = value_counts.sort_values(['customer_id', 'count'], ascending=[True, False])

top_sales = value_counts.drop_duplicates(subset='customer_id', keep='first')
```

Comment: I got the error: TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'value' was passed.    with the code in the comments. It's in the df_melt code line

Comment: provide me with a sample of your `testdf` (not a screen shot)

Comment: also what verson of `pandas` you running?

Comment: try this for that line `df_melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars='customer_id', value_vars=itemCols).dropna(subset=['value'], axis=0)`