# Csv analysis with pandas: Most frequent response of certain rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data has the following structure:

[image: table]

(Each question is repeated six times). Here it is in csv format:

```
Question,Person,Answer
Q_1,p1,3
Q_1,p1,3
Q_1,p1,3
Q_1,p1,3
Q_1,p1,3
Q_1,p1,3
Q_2,p1,1
Q_2,p1,1
Q_2,p1,1
Q_2,p1,1
Q_2,p1,1
Q_2,p1,1
Q_3,p1,1
Q_3,p1,1
Q_3,p1,3
Q_3,p1,1
Q_3,p1,2
Q_3,p1,2
```

What I'm trying to do is find the most frequent answer for each question and create a new .csv file containing only the most frequent answers. For example, the output should look like this:

[image: output]

I tried using `df.mode()` to find the most frequent response, but this returns a single value for the whole column 'Answer'. I need to somehow run it every 6th row and get a separate value for each question. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried `df.groupby` and then apply mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GroupBy pandas DataFrame and select most common value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222754/groupby-pandas-dataframe-and-select-most-common-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas's `groupby` and then apply `agg(pd.Series.mode)` like so:

```py
columns = ["Question","Person","Answer"]
data = [["Q_1","p1",3],
["Q_1","p1",3],
["Q_1","p1",3],
["Q_1","p1",3],
["Q_1","p1",3],
["Q_1","p1",3],
["Q_2","p1",1],
["Q_2","p1",1],
["Q_2","p1",1],
["Q_2","p1",1],
["Q_2","p1",1],
["Q_2","p1",1],
["Q_3","p1",1],
["Q_3","p1",1],
["Q_3","p1",3],
["Q_3","p1",1],
["Q_3","p1",2],
["Q_3","p1",2]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)
df.groupby(["Question"], as_index=False).agg(pd.Series.mode)
```

Output:

```
    Question    Person  Answer
0   Q_1          p1       3
1   Q_2          p1       1
2   Q_3          p1       1
```