# How to use .mode with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

i can use mean and median with groupby with this line:

```
newdf.groupby('dropoff_site')['load_weight'].mean()
newdf.groupby('dropoff_site')['load_weight'].median()
```

But when i use it for mode like this:

```
newdf.groupby('dropoff_site')['load_weight'].mode()
```

An error popped up, saying:
'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'mode'

What should i do?

update:
from [GroupBy pandas DataFrame and select most common value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222754/groupby-pandas-dataframe-and-select-most-common-value) i used

```
source2.groupby(['Country','City'])['Short name'].agg(pd.Series.mode)
```

as

```
newdf.groupby(['dropoff_site'])['load_weight'].agg(pd.Series.mode)
```

because this has multimodal, but now the error goes:
Must produce aggregated value

Comment: This is because `mode` does not necessarily produce a unique value (there can be several modes)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
newdf.groupby('dropoff_site')['load_weight'].agg(pd.Series.mode)
```

Comment: i tried it, the error: "Must produce aggregated value" popped up