# Pandas groupby, keep most common value but drop if tie

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

This is directly based off of the question [GroupBy pandas DataFrame and select most common value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222754/groupby-pandas-dataframe-and-select-most-common-value/74900139#comment134266608_74900139). My goal is to groupby one column, and keep the value that occurs most often in a second column. The solution I am using is `df.groupby(['col1'])['col2'].agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])` I would like to expand on this solution to drop any entries where there is a tie.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GroupBy pandas DataFrame and select most common value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222754/groupby-pandas-dataframe-and-select-most-common-value)

Comment: @pravashpanigrahi as stated in my question, I would like to expand on the answer provided by that post to drop situations where there is a tie. So no, it does not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.Series.mode` to get all the modes, then filter:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': list('aaaabbbb'), 'value': [1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2] })

# output
out = (df.groupby('group')['value'].apply(pd.Series.mode)
         .groupby('group').filter(lambda x: len(x)==1)
      )
```

Output:

```
group   
a      0    1
Name: value, dtype: int64
​
```