# Creating a function to standardize labels for each ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

I am attempting to create a function that standardizes a label column for a given ID for a given criteria.

I would like to standardize the label based on the *most commonly used label* for that ID, and if there is no common/majority label, then just take the first observation as the default standard.

The function I have so far is below:

```
def standardize_labels(df, id_col, label_col):
    # Function to find the most common label or the first one if there's a tie
    def most_common_label(group):
        labels = group[label_col].value_counts()
        # Check if the top two labels have the same count
        if len(labels) > 1 and labels.iloc[0] == labels.iloc[1]:
            return group[label_col].iloc[0]
        return labels.idxmax()

    # Group by the ID column and apply the most_common_label function
    common_labels = df.groupby(id_col).apply(most_common_label)

    # Map the IDs in the original DataFrame to their common labels
    df['standardized_label'] = df[id_col].map(common_labels)

    return df
```

It *mostly* works, however a quirk I've noticed with some where there is an shift in the trend in the labels, the labels then change per a given ID like this:

| ID | raw_label | standardized_label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 222 | LA Metro | LA Metro |
| 222 | LA Metro | LA Metro |
| 222 | Los Angeles Metro | Los Angeles Metro |
| 222 | LA Metro | Los Angeles Metro |
| 222 | Los Angeles Metro | Los Angeles Metro |

When instead the output I'm hoping for all the standardized_label to just be **LA Metro** since that is the majority label per that ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works as expected for me. However, you can use `mode` to make it easier to read. Also you can transform a function in groupby as well to assign directly to a column, which then would make your entire operation into a single line of code.

```py
df['standardized_label'] = df.groupby('ID')['raw_label'].transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
```

Or you can use `groupby.apply` and map it as well. Anyway, the function would look like:

```py
def standardize_labels(df, id_col, label_col):
    # Function to find the most common label or the first one if there's a tie
    def most_common_label(group):
        return group.mode()[0]

    # Group by the ID column and apply the most_common_label function
    common_labels = df.groupby(id_col)[label_col].apply(most_common_label)

    # Map the IDs in the original DataFrame to their common labels
    df['standardized_label'] = df[id_col].map(common_labels)

    return df
```

Since `value_counts()` works on a dataframe, we can use it directly without the groupby. So the function could be changed to the following. This is a refactoring of [a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72427324/19123103) I wrote for a different question.

```py
def standardize_labels(df, id_col, label_col):
    # Group by the ID column and apply the most_common_label function
    labels_counts = df.value_counts([id_col, label_col])
    dup_idx_msk = ~labels_counts.droplevel(label_col).index.duplicated()
    common_labels = labels_counts[dup_idx_msk]
    common_labels = common_labels.reset_index(level=1)[label_col]
    # Map the IDs in the original DataFrame to their common labels
    df['standardized_label'] = df[id_col].map(common_labels)
    return df

df = standardize_labels(df, 'ID', 'raw_label')
```